# How to force GCC compiler to calculate constants at compile-time with -Os

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

I tried to calculate hashes for constant C-strings in compile-time using macros. That is my example code:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t hash_t;

#define hash_cstr(s) ({           \
      typeof(sizeof(s)) i = 0;    \
      hash_t h = 5381;            \
      for (; i < sizeof(s) - 1; ) \
        h = h * 33 + s[i++];      \
      h;                          \
    })

/* tests */
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
#define test(s) printf("The djb2 hash of " #s " is a %u\n", hash_cstr(#s))

  test(POST);
  test(/path/to/file);
  test(Content-Length);
}
```

Now I run **GCC** to show listing:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.8 -S -O2 -funroll-loops -o hash_test.S hash_test.c
```

And the result is as expected: all strings was eliminated and replaced by its hashes. But generally I use *-Os* to compile code of embedded apps. When I try to do it, I have hashes only for strings with less than four characters. I also tried to set parameter `max-unroll-times` and use **GCC 4.9**:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.9 -S -Os -funroll-loops \
  --param max-unroll-times=128 -o hash_test.S hash_test.c
```

I can't understand the reason of that behavior and how I can extend this restriction of four chars.

Comment: Use a `constexpr` function rather than a macro ?

Comment: But `constexpr` is for C++, and the example looks like C code

Comment: And also filename is `.c`. It's not C++. Why was I summoned here?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch but OP explicitely said that he is using C++ by mentioning it and not C in tags, right?

Comment: I guess that since the code is purely C99, the file suffix is `.c`, hence the OP wants in fact C (not C++) and might have tagged his question wrongly.

Comment: Of course, I use pure C.

Comment: The [GCC documentation on optimization flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) made me believe `-Os` and `-O2` only enable/disable `-fxxx` flags. I tried to compile with all optimization flags enabled and disable them one by one until I find a suitable combination near `-Os` enough for OP. To my surprise, it didn't worked: `gcc -S -fauto-inc-dec -fcprop-registers -fdce -fdefer-pop ... -fomit-frame-pointer -funroll-loops -o hash_test.S hash_test.c && cat hash_test.S` : there is no hash :(

Comment: I implemented a preprocessing tool, because I need static const hashes in common case. Advanced compile-time evaluation is a bottleneck of C.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest putting the relevant code in a separate file and compile that file with `-O2` (not with `-Os`). Or put a [function specific pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) like

```
 #pragma GCC optimize ("-O2")
```

before the function, or use a [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) like `__attribute__((optimize("02")))` (and the `pure` attribute probably is also relevant)

You might be interested by [`__builtin_constant_p`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins).

I would make your hashing code some `static inline` function (perhaps with `always_inline` function attribute), e.g.

```
 static inline hash_t hashfun(const char*s) {
    hash_t h = 5381;
    for (const char* p = s; *p; p++) 
      h = h * 33 + *p;
    return h;
 }
```

---

A more portable (and less brittle) alternative is to change your build procedure to generate some C file (e.g. with a simple `awk` or `python` script, or even an ad-hoc C program) containing things like

```
  const char str1[]="POST";
  hash_t hash1=2089437419; // the hash code of str1
```

Don't forget that `.c` or `.h` files can be generated by something else (you'll just need to add some rules inside your `Makefile` to generate them); if your boss feels uneasy about that show him the [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) wikipage.

Comment: Yes, I use `__builtin_constant_p` in real code, but this is simplified example to  test possibility of hash calculation at compile-time.

Comment: The `static inline` function actually don't calculated at compile-time with GCC < 4.9.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found a workaround, which is limited by length. It looks like a dirty hack but works as expected with any **GCC** toolchain.

```c
#define _hash_cstr_4(s, o)                \
  for (; i < ((o + 4) < sizeof(s) - 1 ?   \
              (o + 4) : sizeof(s) - 1); ) \
    h = h * 33 + s[i++]

#define _hash_cstr_16(s, o)           \
  _hash_cstr_4(s, o);                 \
  _hash_cstr_4(s, o + 4);             \
  _hash_cstr_4(s, o + 8);             \
  _hash_cstr_4(s, o + 12)

#define _hash_cstr_64(s, o)           \
  _hash_cstr_16(s, o);                \
  _hash_cstr_16(s, o + 16);           \
  _hash_cstr_16(s, o + 32);           \
  _hash_cstr_16(s, o + 48)

#define _hash_cstr_256(s, o)          \
  _hash_cstr_64(s, o);                \
  _hash_cstr_64(s, o + 64);           \
  _hash_cstr_64(s, o + 128);          \
  _hash_cstr_64(s, o + 192)

#define hash_cstr(s) ({                  \
      typeof(sizeof(s)) i = 0;           \
      hash_t h = 5381;                   \
      if (sizeof(s) - 1 < 256) {         \
        _hash_cstr_256(s, 0);            \
      } else                             \
        for (; i < sizeof(s) - 1; )      \
          h = h * 33 + s[i++];           \
      h;                                 \
    })
```

When the length of hashed string is lesser than *256* characters, it calculates hash at compile time, otherwise it calculates hash at runtime.

This solution does not require additional tuning of compiler. It works with *-Os* and *-O1* too.

Answer (score 0):

If C++ is alowed give a channce to template function, something like:

```
template<int I>
  hash_t hash_rec(const char* str, hash_t h) {
  if( I > 0 ) {
    return hash_rec<I-1>(str, h * 33 + str[I-1]);
  } else {
    return h;
  }
}

#define hash(str) hash_rec<sizeof(str)>(str, 5381)

h = hash(str);
```

Comment: Of course, I know things like this, but I avoid to use C++ in favour of pure C.